# Show a matrix M is invertible if and only if the eigenvalues of A are all distinct

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$,
define a matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}n&tr({A})&tr({A^2})&\cdots&tr(A^{n-1})\\tr({A}) &tr({A^2})&tr({A^3})&\cdots&tr({A}^n)\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\ tr({A}^{n-2}) &tr({A^{n-1}})&tr({A^{n}})&\cdots&tr({A}^{2n-1})\\
tr({A}^{n-1}) &tr({A^n})&tr({A^{n+1}})&\cdots&tr({A}^{2n-2})\end{pmatrix}$$

Can we show that $M$ is invertible if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are all distinct? I have a feeling that this relates to the Vandermonde matrix. I also have some work using the linearity of trace and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Do we have any other thoughts as to how to approach this problem?

Note that the matrix is complex, so we do not know if it is diagonalizable.

Comment: I would guess that the fact that the trace can be expresses using the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ according to $\text{tr}(A^k) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i^k$ should play a part. We'll see if that is the case.

Comment: It is reminiscent of a Vandermonde matrix, but it doesn't appear to be one.

Comment: Could we factor $M$ as the Vandermonde matrix times its transpose perhaps....? There seems to be an inkling of something there. I will keep thinking on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, and consider the Vandermonde matrix

$$ V = V(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \ldots & 1 \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ \lambda_1^{n-1} & \ldots & \lambda_n^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $$

Then

$$VV^T = \begin{bmatrix} n  & \ldots & \sum_i \lambda_i^{n-1} \\ \vdots &  & \vdots \\ \sum_i \lambda_i^{n-1} & \ldots & \sum_i \lambda_i^{2n - 2} \end{bmatrix} = M$$

Therefore $M$ is invertible if and only if $V$ is invertible if and only if the $\lambda_i$'s are distinct.

Comment: Okay yes. This seems to be what I was looking at trying.